# Pandas pd.read_csv - has anything changed?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a piece of code I wrote with Jupyter  ~1 year ago which successfully used

```
 dg = pd.read_csv(f10,sep=';')
```

to read this data

```
A;W
83;88,0
64;70,1
94;94,2
```

Today I get:

```
OSError: Initializing from file failed
```

and somewhere inbetween:

```
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
    964     def _make_engine(self, engine='c'):
    965         if engine == 'c':
--> 966             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
    967         else:
    968             if engine == 'python':
```

This, however, works today:

```
with open(f10, newline='') as csvfile:
    data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
```

Since I prefere the Pandas-way, has anybody an idea what I should change ? Tx for hints !

**Edit :**
I've just found out, that this works too:

```
with open(f10, newline='') as csvfile:
    dg = pd.read_csv(csvfile, delimiter=';')
```

But is that really necessary ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem comes from `newline` which is expected to be `\n` by `pandas`.

You can pass a buffer directly to `pd.read_csv()`:

```
dg = pd.read_csv(open(f10, newline=''), sep=';')
```

Comment: In my case **this works** ! @FabienP  Thank you for your support !

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
import sys

pd.read_csv(f10, sep=';', encoding=sys.getdefaultencoding())
```

**UPDATE:**

it could also be [caused by characters with accents in the path or filename](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15086), so try to move/rename the path/filename to have an ASCII characters only and try it again...

Comment: @ MaxU: I tryied your propositions, both. In my case, the answer of *FabienP* was successful. Thank you for your support !